# How to read until EOF of a excel document

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm hard-coding where I'd like to read the file until like 100 entries, but is there something that I can do to read the the document until the end of the file so I don't have to hard-code it?

In the document I want the first and second field and I was just putting the first and last names into a `.txt` file for later use.

```
$i
$n
for($n = 1 ; $n -lt 100; $n++)
{
    $test = (Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\Lab8_db1.csv")[$n].Split(",")

    for($i = 0 ;  $i -lt 1;  $i++)
    {  
        (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($test[$i]) >> "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\FirstNames.txt"

        for($i = 1 ;  $i -lt 2;  $i++)
        {  
            (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($test[$i]) >> "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\LastNames.txt"
        }
    }    
}
```

CSV File:

```
YlnuM   vYBgHjv 558 3/14/2013   (905)-555-5656  1"&;DrO

dexCd   MnYUAit 908 12/3/2010   (905)-555-5656  ZT/J*0Og

IgbOs   NLBiHJZ 85  10/6/2011   (905)-555-5656  EnxoZo@x

rZJlR   wDdbCJP 580 4/5/2010    (905)-555-5656  Uz*<=e>y
```

Output Firstnames.txt:

```
Ylnum

Dexcd

Igbos

Rzjlr
```

LastNames.txt:

```
Vybghjv

Mnyuait

Nlbihjz

Wddbcjp
```

Comment: can you add some detail as to what you want the output to look like and add a small copy of your csv file as well?

Comment: no problem look at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$CsvContent = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\Lab8_db1.csv" | Select-Object -First 100
Foreach ( $Line in $CsvContent )
{
    $Line.FirstName | Add-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\FirstNames.txt
    $Line.LastName | Add-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\LastNames.txt
}
```

This is assuming that your column names are 'FirstName' and 'LastName'

Comment: Was using `$_` instead of `$Line`. Fixed

Comment: His CSV does not appear to have headers, so you would need to do `Import-Csv $path -Header 'FirstName','LastName','EmpID','Date','Phone','Password'` to supply the headers when you import it.